# How to get the Number of Drawn Triangles reliably in Unreal?

Tags: gpu, rendering, profiling, unreal-engine5

I am desperately looking for a way to reliably get the average number of triangles drawn during a selected time window in UE 5.1. When I use command line tools for that I get weird numbers. For example, for a scene with a single object that has 220 triangles, RHI Triangles Drawn gives an average of 1607.5 over a 10 second window. I think Unreal includes the number of triangles to render the text it prints on screen (the text on upper left in the image below) which appears when I use command Stat StartFile
[image: unreal]

I also tried Unreal Insights but I couldn’t find a way to get an average count of triangles drawn over a period from that.

Any ideas to reliably get it?